# Kotlin addTextChangeListener lambda?

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, anko

How do you build a lambda expression for the EditText addTextChangeListener in Kotlin? Below gives an error:

```
passwordEditText.addTextChangedListener { charSequence  ->
    try {
        password = charSequence.toString()
    } catch (error: Throwable) {
        raise(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: What error does it gives?

Comment: Hi think my question is edited to suit his answer.

Answer (score -11, accepted):

This looks neat:

```
passwordEditText.setOnEditorActionListener { 
    textView, keyCode, keyEvent ->
    val DONE = 6

    if (keyCode == DONE) {                       
         // your code here
    }
    false
}
```

Comment: I really don't know with you guys but my answer worked for me and is shorter than the answer above and below..

Comment: This works as what the code intends to be, performs action once DONE is pressed. I modified the code by placing a toast outside the condition and it seems to only fires when pressing TAB/DONE/etc. but not on other characters.

Answer (score 362):

`addTextChangedListener()` takes a [`TextWatcher`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) which is an interface with 3 methods. What you wrote would only work if `TextWatcher` had only 1 method. I'm going to guess the error you're getting relates to your lambda not implementing the other 2 methods. You have 2 options going forward.

1. Ditch the lambda and just use an anonymous inner class

```
    editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
      override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
      }
    
      override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
      }
    
      override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
      }
    })
```

2. Create an extension method so you can use a lambda expression:

```
    fun EditText.afterTextChanged(afterTextChanged: (String) -> Unit) {
        this.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
          override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
          }
    
          override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
          }
    
          override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable?) {
            afterTextChanged.invoke(editable.toString())
          }
        })
    }
```

And then use the extension like so:

```
editText.afterTextChanged { doSomethingWithText(it) }
```

Comment: Not sure if personal preference or better style, but your extension function could be converted to an expression body (`fun foo() = ...`)

Comment: @mEQ5aNLrK3lqs3kfSa5HbvsTWe0nIu You're right that it can be converted. However, for functions longer than one line, I like having surrounding brackets to clearly mark where the function starts and stops. I believe it increases readability, but it's totally a style preference. I think it could be argued both ways :)

Comment: Out of interest: Why call `afterTextChanged.invoke(...)` instead of `afterTextChanged(...)`?

Comment: This worked for me. I preferred the 2nd option for reusability.

Comment: But if that wouldn't be possible, why does the IDE allow the addTextChangedListener{} at all? The code for that however looks like this: public inline fun TextView.addTextChangedListener(
    crossinline beforeTextChanged: (
        text: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int,  after: Int
    ) -> Unit = { _, _, _, _ -> },
[...]
    crossinline afterTextChanged: (text: Editable?) -> Unit = {}
): TextWatcher

Answer (score 100):

Add this core ktx dependence

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.0'
```

You simply have to do

`passwordEditText.doAfterTextChanged{ }`

Answer (score 34):

A bit old, but using Kotlin Android extensions you can do something like that:

```
editTextRequest.textChangedListener {
            afterTextChanged {
                // Do something here...
            }
}
```

No extra code needed, just add:

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.0'
```

Comment: That's not working for me, even after refactoring to android X. Any guess to what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Does not work for me as well. It looks like KTX does not provide this extension anymore, however,  `KAndroid ` solution works perfectly.

Comment: with ktx:1.0.1 you can use https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/widget/package-summary#extension-functions

Comment: `implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0"` -> `edt.addTextChangedListener(afterTextChanged = { /*dosomething*/ })`

Comment: It's easier to just use editTextRequest.doAfterTextChanged { ... }

Answer (score 21):

Sorry for being late!

If you add `implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'` to your module's build.gradle file then you can use

```
etPlayer1.doOnTextChanged { text, start, count, after -> // Do stuff }
```

Answer (score 19):

Test it :

```
passwordEditText.addTextChangedListener(object:TextWatcher{
    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) { }

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) { }

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) { }
})
```

Answer (score 15):

hope this `Kotlin` sample help making it clear:

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false)

    view.user.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {

        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
                userLayout.error =
                        if (s.length > userLayout.counterMaxLength) {
                            "Max character length is: ${userLayout.counterMaxLength}"
                        } else null
        }
    })
    return view
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
    // TODO: Use the ViewModel
   }
}
```

With this `XML` layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/userLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:counterMaxLength="5"
    app:counterEnabled="true"
    android:hint="user_name">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/user"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

And this `Gradle`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
...
}
    api 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1' // appcompat library
```

Answer (score 15):

In case you're using Material [Filled text field](https://material.io/components/text-fields/android#filled-text-field) or [Outlined text field](https://material.io/components/text-fields/android#outlined-text-field), attempt to respond to input text change as mentioned by documentation, respectively:

```
filledTextField.editText?.doOnTextChanged { inputText, _, _, _ ->
    // Respond to input text change
}
```

and

```
outlinedTextField.editText?.doOnTextChanged { inputText, _, _, _ ->
    // Respond to input text change
}
```

Answer (score 12):

if you use `implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0-alpha05'` you can use

```
For android.widget.TextView
TextWatcher 
TextView.doBeforeTextChanged(crossinline action: (text: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) -> Unit)
Add an action which will be invoked before the text changed.

TextWatcher 
TextView.doOnTextChanged(crossinline action: (text: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) -> Unit)
Add an action which will be invoked when the text is changing.

TextWatcher 
TextView.doAfterTextChanged(crossinline action: (text: Editable?) -> Unit)
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/widget/package-summary#extension-functions

Answer (score 11):

Add the core ktx dependency

`implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'`

And you can simply implement like this

```java
    edit_text.addTextChangedListener { it: Editable? ->
      // Do your stuff here
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is the `KAndroid` library -

`implementation 'com.pawegio.kandroid:kandroid:0.8.7@aar'`

Then you could do something like this...

```
editText.textWatcher { afterTextChanged { doSomething() } }
```

Obviously it is excessive to use an entire library to solve your problem, but it also comes with a range of other useful extensions that eliminate boilerplate code in the Android SDK.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of kotlin's named parameters:

```
private val beforeTextChangedStub: (CharSequence, Int, Int, Int) -> Unit = { _, _, _, _ -> }
private val onTextChangedStub: (CharSequence, Int, Int, Int) -> Unit = { _, _, _, _ -> }
private val afterTextChangedStub: (Editable) -> Unit = {}

fun EditText.addChangedListener(
        beforeTextChanged: (CharSequence, Int, Int, Int) -> Unit = beforeTextChangedStub,
        onTextChanged: (CharSequence, Int, Int, Int) -> Unit = onTextChangedStub,
        afterTextChanged: (Editable) -> Unit = afterTextChangedStub
) = addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
    override fun beforeTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {
        beforeTextChanged(charSequence, i, i1, i2)
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {
        onTextChanged(charSequence, i, i1, i2)
    }

    override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {
        afterTextChanged(editable)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

**This is the lambda function with edit text field with TextWatcher**

```
searchField.addTextChangedListener(
        afterTextChanged = {

        },
        onTextChanged = {s, start, before, count->
            TODO("DO your code")
        },
        beforeTextChanged = {s, start, before, count->
           TODO("DO your code")
        }
    )
```