# sharedPreferences doesn't work in Android (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

There is an edittext in this application, and the purpose of this application is that when the user writes text or anything String in the edittext, after the user closes the application and reopens it, the text is saved in sharedPreferences and the text is again in the field. or the same edittext exists and the user can write the continuation of his text
But normally, when the program is closed, all the text written by the user will be deleted

MainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var editText:EditText
    private val name = "MY_TEXT"
    private val key = "myStoredData"
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editTextText)
    }
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        var sharedPref:SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(name, MODE_PRIVATE)
        var myValue = sharedPref.getString(key,"")
        editText.setText(myValue)
    }
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        var sharedPref:SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(name, MODE_PRIVATE)
        var edit = sharedPref.edit()
        edit.putString(key,editText.text.toString())
        edit.apply()
    }
}
```

Activity_main.xml:

```
    <EditText
        android:hint="test"
        android:id="@+id/editTextText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Thank you for helping me

Comment: Don't save you data on onDestroy - [Activity onDestroy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29). Save your data in 'onPause' or use [edit text text change listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40569436/kotlin-addtextchangelistener-lambda)

Answer (score 1):

When an app is killed by the system, the `onDestroy()` method of the activity may not be executed. Therefore, it's better to place the commit of `SharedPreferences` in `onPause()` or `onStop()`. However, this is not 100% effective either. Perhaps using `WorkManager` can increase the success rate.

Answer (score 0):

try Changing

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    var sharedPref:SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(name, MODE_PRIVATE)
    var myValue = sharedPref.getString(key,"")
    editText.setText(myValue)
}
override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    var sharedPref:SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(name, MODE_PRIVATE)
    var edit = sharedPref.edit()
    edit.putString(key,editText.text.toString())
    edit.apply()
}
```

}